# Is there a way to use one variable for all routes in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a project where I got a task to change the language in the URL and render it, for example, right now my URL looks like this /home/component/new and I need it to be /:language/home/component/new
My routes page looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home/:searchKey/:page',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/music/:artist',
    component: MusicComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '/video/:name',
    component: VideoComponent,
  },
];
```

I know I can do it if I make a variable and change it like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':language/home/:searchKey/:page',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':language/music/:artist',
    component: MusicComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':language/video/:name',
    component: VideoComponent,
  },
];
```

But is there a way to declare this variable and use it automatically in every route I ever make without having to write :language for every new route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you should instead use the Angular i18N tool, which is made exactly for this kind of need.

But to answer you

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':lang',
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'music', component: MusicComponent },
      // ...
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Hi! This project is already using i18N tools, it's not my project but I have to work with it now, I didn't know there is a way to add a language to URL, the tool is used in the project but the url isn't there, maybe I don't know something, how can I add it to the url?

Comment: There's i18n tools, then there's angular one. Check which one is used. You can use my snippet to add the language to the url like you wanted anyway!